# Spring Batch JUnit 5 JobLauncherTestUtils is not initialized

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, junit5

I am trying to load the JobLauncherTestUtils object in a JUnit 5 and SpringBatchTest annotation. However, it fails to load the application context. All the other autowired beans load successfully, but the JobLauncherTestUtils fails to load. Here is my test configuration, omitting the imports. I tried manually loading it in BeforeAll but then the JobRepository and JobLauncher fail to load. I am only interested in being able to instantiate JobLauncherTestUtils successfully. Please help!

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@SpringBatchTest
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class ,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class})
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
@EnableAutoConfiguration  
public class ProductsProcessorTest {

    @Autowired
    JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Autowired
    private JobRepositoryTestUtils jobRepositoryTestUtils;

    @MockBean
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    JobRepository jobRepository;

    @Autowired
    OrderManagementService orderManagementService;

    @MockBean
    Job keyLoaderJob;

    @Autowired
    @JobScope
    static ProductsLoader productsLoader;

    //Tried manually instantiating it, but then would l
    @BeforeAll
    static void setUp() throws Exception {
        //jobLauncherTestUtils = new JobLauncherTestUtils();
    }

    //This does not work either
    @BeforeEach
    void init(){
        // jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher);
        // jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    }

    // ....

   }
```

Here is the exception I get:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobLauncherTestUtils': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setJobRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. The error was Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: TransactionManager must not be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository' available

This error means there is no `JobRepository` bean defined in your test application context. Make sure you import the class where this bean is defined.

Comment: I do have a bean defined actually or the class would not even compile.  All the required beans are defined but the context does not load.

Comment: No, it could compile if the bean is defined in another class. There is no JobRepository bean defined in `ProductsProcessorTest` and there is no `@import` that imports another class where this bean could be defined. Please edit the question and share a minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to be able to help you in an efficient manner.

Comment: I got to work with what you suggested. i created a configuration class for the job repository and the jobLauncher.  The class was broken in the first place.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the error  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: TransactionManager must not be null.

Comment: I solved it by adding :             jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(new DataSourceTransactionManager());